# React Redux state updated but ui not reloads & if copy a data from redux state and then overwrite that data it will automatically update redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If I clone / copy array from the redux state and override it, and then redux state automatically updated with the modified data.

I don't how it updated, kindly help to resolve this issue.

I have used useSelector to map with redux state.

Comment: can you please add the code because I am not able to understand your issue clearly

Comment: Okay sure I will add..